# C++ - second level of protected code in user space code

Tags: c++, assembly, sandbox

Given this code:

```cpp
class module {
  public:
    virtual void run(void (*callback)(int)) = 0;
    byte* memory;
}
int main() {
  module m1 = loadSomeUntrustedModule();
  module m2 = loadSomeUntrustedModule();
  m1.memory[31] = 5;
  //m1.run(); //?
  return m1.memory[32];
}
```

I want to execute `run` in `module` that cannot access code outside of itself, isolating it with its own private memory space, only accessible from the main process.  Safe from memory leaks, and potentially from malicious code.  The code does not need access to anything but its own memory.  I intend for this code to be cross-platform, compiling and running for linux, windows, mac, android, etc...

Its a rather simple question; How do I run sandboxed/protected code in c++ with the requirements talked about above?  But one much more complicated to answer I would assume.  One that I would assume to be containing assembly.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @OznOg My bad, I am asking how do I run protected code as I have defined above.

Comment: If you run code in a process, it may access only memory allocated in this process. This is granted by MS Windows, Linux (on a PC), and OS X as well. [Memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection)

Comment: Have you tried starting a new process for the untrusted code and using some IPC mechanism to interact with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's cross-platform solution available to load module into the same process (moreover, we don't have cross-platform modules yet).

More-or-less portable solution would be to create another process and use cross-process communication. They are still different for different OSes, but cross-platform wrappers do exist.

One known implementation is Google Chrome sandbox. On Windows it creates sub-processes, reduces their access tokens to very minimum and hooks their file i/o system APIs to forward data thru pipes to parent process. Good sandbox is *that* hard...

Comment: The cross-platform solution is the `system()` function call (given that the other code has no dependencies it doesn't belong in the same executable in the first place).